# Google Glass mirror client api usage limit issue

Tags: google-mirror-api, google-glass

I have been working on an app for Google Glass. The project was working fine until couple of days ago. Now it is giving an error and upon checking it I found I have exceeded my quota for the day.

Error below:

```
Uncaught exception from servlet
com.google.api.client.googleapis.json.GoogleJsonResponseException: 403
{
  "code" : 403,
  "errors" : [ {
    "domain" : "usageLimits",
    "message" : "Daily Limit Exceeded",
    "reason" : "dailyLimitExceeded"
  } ],
  "message" : "Daily Limit Exceeded"
}
    at com.google.api.client.googleapis.json.GoogleJsonResponseException.from(GoogleJsonResponseException.java:145)
```

Now the issues is, even after a day from the time it said I have expired my quota, I still continue to see the same error.

Is there any total usage cap on the Mirror API?

How can I increase the daily usage limit?

Answer (score 7):

Yes there is a daily usage limit.

You can find yours at the API console: https://code.google.com/apis/console/

In the upper left click "Quotas" and look for the Effective Limits for the Google Mirror API.

Mine are set to 10 requests/second/user and 1000 requests per day.

[image]

Probably yours are the same.

The 24 hour period by which your quota is reset I am unsure of, but I bet if you wait the service will become available again.

As for increasing the usage limit, I am not aware of any way to request that.  For now I would try to limit usage to less than 1000 requests per day.

Comment: In my case, the quota is the same. However, whenever we insert 3 cards to the glasses, the usage increases by 1%. I think the limit is less than 1000 requests / day.